# removing a variable from a list of comma seperated email ids

Tags: python

I have the following subroutine which I use for sending email,I am trying to remove a user "username1" from the variable "to" which is a comma seperated email ids',am using to=to.strip('username1') which doesnt seem to work,any idea how to remove username1@company.com from the variable "to"

```
def email (body,subject,to=None):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    msg["From"] = "serviceaccount@company.com"
    if to!=None:
        to=to.strip()
        to=to.strip('username1@company.com')
        msg["To"] = to
        print to
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it out by comma, then join back them back on comma minus the excluded one...

```
msg['To'] = ','.join(email for email in msg['To'].split(',') if email != 'username1@company.com')
```

You could also generalise it to have a list of "do not mails", eg:

```
DO_NOT_MAIL = ['username1@companyname.com', 'username2@anothercompany.com']

def email(body, subject, to=None):
    msg = MIMEText("%s" % body)
    msg["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
    msg["From"] = "serviceaccount@company.com"
    msg["To"] = ', '.join(email for email in set(to).difference(DO_NOT_MAIL))
```